# multiple id in sql how to expload and get the id values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Multiple id in mysql table how to expload and get the particular id values in another mysql table for codeigniter**,

Pages view images added,

**View page**

```
   `<?php foreach($company_branch as $loop){  ?>
    <tr> 
    <td></td>
    <td><?=$loop->branch_name ?></td>
    <td><?=$loop->branch_head ?></td>
    <td><?=$loop->departments_list_id ?></td>
    <td><?=$loop->write_date ?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php } ?>`
```

**Controller Page**

```
      `public function company_settings() {
        $data['company_branch'] = $this->settings_model->company_branch();
      $this->load->view('settings/company_settings',$data);`
```

**Model Page**

```
   `function company_branch(){    
    $this->db->select('company_branch.*,
       company_departments.department_name as departments_name  ')-
    >from('company_branch');
     $this->db- >join('company_departments',' 
    company_branch.departments_list_id = company_departments.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query->result();
    }`


  How to display the `departments_list_id ` to department names in view 
  page,
```

[The image is company_branch and company_department mysql table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lYuk.jpg),

[browser View page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8n2P.jpg,),

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how to display the department_names in browser view page departments column  not in id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View Page**

```
          `<?php foreach($company_branch as $loop){  ?>
             <tr> 
            <td></td>
            <td><?=$loop->branch_name ?></td>
            <td><?=$loop->branch_head ?></td>
            <td>
               <?php   
                  foreach(explode(",",$loop->departments_list_id) as $department)
                  {  $depart=$this->db->query("select department_name from company_departments where id=".$department)->row()->department_name;
                  echo $depart.',<br />';
                 }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$loop->write_date ?></td>
             </tr>
             <?php } ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter some id into 1 field. You can add some fields to another id. Example field: departement_id_1, departement_id_2, departement_id_4, departement_id_5 etc depending on need.

you can change your sql select to this :

```
select branc.*,
(select dept.departement_name as departement_name_1 from company_departement as dept where branc.departement_id_1=dept.id),
(select dept.departement_name as departement_name_2 from company_departement as dept where branc.departement_id_2=dept.id),
(select dept.departement_name as departement_name_3 from company_departement as dept where branc.departement_id_2=dept.id)
from company_branc as b
```

then you can use script from your form

```
    <?php foreach($company_branch as $loop){  ?>
    <tr> 
    <td></td>
    <td><?=$loop->branch_name ?></td>
    <td><?=$loop->branch_head ?></td>
    <td><?=$loop->departments_name_1 ?></br>
<?=$loop->departments_name_2 ?></br>
<?=$loop->departments_name_3 ?>
</td>
    <td><?=$loop->write_date ?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

i hope this helps